# how to return null from recursive method in java

Tags: java

i'm trying to write a selection sort recursively in java, but I want it to return null if I pass the array as null and the method is void.

this is my base case so far

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] array, int index)
  {
    if (index == array.length - 1 || array.length < 1)
    {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to return null? Why do you want to return anything? If the method is void, it cannot return anything.

Comment: A void method cannot return anything, including null. So what you are trying to do is impossible. Either change the method from void to something else or live with the method not returning anything.

Comment: Now that i look at the code again: Is there any chance you are getting a NullPointerException when you pass null as an array into that method and what to change it so you don't get a NPE? in that case just add `if(array==null){return;}` to the beginning of your method.

Comment: It is not good practice to treat null as a valid value.  Good practice is to document the method as requiring a non-null value, and either check for null yourself using [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)), or let a NullPointerException happen naturally.  If someone wants to pass an empty array, it’s easy to type `new int[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider **not to use null as a return-value**. It is bad practice.
Anyways, basically you want to check if your array is `null`. Simply use an if-statement.

But you will also need to change the return-type, of your method, as void functions can't return anything!

```
public static int selectionSort(int[] array, int index) {
    if(array == null){
        return 1;
    }
    if (index == array.length - 1 || array.length < 1)
    {
      return 0;
    }
}
```